# Deploy yew with nginx

Tags: nginx, rust, yew

I am trying to deploy a yew app with nginx but when I do, I am unable to visit other pages. I can only go to `/`, but I also have for example a `/profile/1234` route. Locally if I run the app with `trunk serve` I can access that page. But on my server I get a 500 error.

From what I read on https://yew.rs/docs/next/more/deployment, it seems you only need to compile the project with `trunk build --release` and serve from the `dist/` directory (index.html, a js and a wasm file). Maybe I have to do something more here? Also, clicking a link from within the `/` page works, but refreshing the page or manually going to a page doesn't.

My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/project` configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name <public_ip>;
        location / {
                     root /var/www/frontend/dist;
                     index index.html;
                     try_files $uri $uri/ /front/index.html;
        }
}
```

Comment: You get a 500 error from nginx serving static files? Sounds like a server configuration error. Check nginx logs.

Comment: Do either of these answer your question? [rust yew app working on local laptop/pc not behind nginx](/q/76765046/2189130) or [rust yew with wasm issue at deployment](/q/76751442/2189130)